# Extraer info de la tabla que no aparece en el HTML. Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium

buen día!
estoy tratando de extraer un importe de una tabla que no aparece en el HTML. Surge toda la estructura de la tabla pero no el contenido.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el HTML del elemento es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No logro encontrar la manera de poder extraer ese importe.

Mi código que busca localizarlo es:

```
String V_Ene;
    V_Ene= "//tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/input[1]";
    
    String V_ene_ =driver.findElement(By.xpath(V_Ene)).getText().toString();
    
    if(V_ene_=="") {
        V_ene_="Vacio";
    }else {
        System.out.println("El valor es"+ V_ene_);
    }
```

les ruego vuestra ayuda, estoy trabado en este paso.
Graciasss!!!